# Babel will result in define inside define

Tags: javascript, requirejs, babeljs

My current project uses requirejs. Now I tried to run Babel (grunt-babel) to support ES6. Unfortunately the end-result is a define inside define.
Any idea how to prevent/handle this?

Before Babel

```
define(["someModuleReference"], function (someModule) {...});
```

After Babel

```
define(["exports"], function (exports) {
    "use strict";
    define(["someModuleReference"], function (someModule) {...});
});
```

Here is the grunt babel config:

```
babel: {
    options: {
        sourceMaps: true,
        modules: 'amd'
    },
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'www/js',
            src: ['**/*.js'],
            dest: 'www/jstrans'
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the babel configuration you use please ?

Comment: @Xartok config just added in the question part.

Comment: Ok so the first thing is that **modules: 'amd'** in the options is the output module system used. Then, you use requirejs on the input, so you should use a tool that takes requirejs-es6 to give requirejs-es5. Babel [recommend](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#requirejs) using _requirejs-babel_ module to do that.

Comment: @Xartok There is no documentation for the require-js babel task. What should be the config(in gruntfile.js), which I have to replace with the babel one?

Comment: `modules: 'amd` converts an ES6 module into an AMD module, the fact that you already have some AMD in your module is your code mistake. If you're already using AMD modules directly, you should just disable `modules` entirely, or use ES6 module instead.

Comment: @Xartok +1 for the effort and requirejs-babel suggestion. I finally removed all requirejs modules and use only es6 modules. Took some time, but clean endresult.